# Remove duplication related to MAX date

Tags: sql-server

How to remove data from a table with other than max date in SQL server?
I have tried the where condition like 
`(HAVING MAX(dated) != date)` but its not working.

Let suppose we have a table having Several columns. 1st is Mobile Number and second is Date and remaining are **bla bla**. Mobile Numbers are repeated with different dates now I want to delete those mobile numbers that haven't MAX date. In other works I want to keep only those numbers having MAX date and remove duplication.

Kindly Help..

Comment: Please edit your question to include at least the relevant table's DDL, some DML for sample data and desired results

Comment: Dear @ZoharPeled Post is now edited, kindly comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using an inner join to a derived table in your delete statement:

Create and populate sample table (Please save us this step in your next question)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE 
(
    Mobile char(1),
    Dated date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('A', GETDATE()),
('A', GETDATE() - 1),
('A', GETDATE() + 2),
('B', GETDATE() - 1),
('B', GETDATE() + 3),
('B', GETDATE())
```

Delete statement

```
DELETE T1
FROM @T T1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Mobile, MAX(Dated) as Dated
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Mobile
) T2
ON T1.Mobile = T2.Mobile 
WHERE T1.Dated < T2.Dated
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @Zohar

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

One more way with the help of OUTER APPLY:

```
DELETE FROM y
FROM YourTable y
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT top 1 * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE y.ID = ID
    ORDER BY dated DESC
) as y2
WHERE CAST(y.dated as date) < CAST(y2.dated as date)
```

Comment: According to this sub query All data will be deleted except the only one MAX date, so this not effective.

Comment: I changed my answer, please, check.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to Delete the records other than Max date

```
DECLARE @maxDate DATE

SELECT TOP 1 @maxDate = CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
FROM <Table1>
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC

DELETE
FROM <Table1>
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE) != @maxDate
```

Please mark this as answer if this query fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Sorry dear this query is not meeting my requirement. Thank you your quick response.